# Can I use the output from a ZSH custom function in Tmux's status bar?

Tags: zsh, tmux

I defined a function in ~/.zshrc:

```
foo() { print "FOO" }
```

I'd like to output it in my Tmux status bar. I added this to ~/.tmux.conf:

```
set -g status-right "foo: #(foo)"
```

But I only see the static portion of that; the function output is missing. (While my actual function is more complicated, this is true even for the trivial example above.)

It works fine when I call a script instead of a function. What's the difference? Is it possible to use a function there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `tmux` man page states for the `set` option:

> `#(shell-command)` First line of the command's output

But I'm pretty sure, that does not mean shell *funcitons*, because `tmux` will not execute the `shell-command` in the current shell-session, but start a new instance, which starts as *non-interactive*, hence does not source your `~/.zshrc` config and so does not know about functions defined therein.

To work round, you could create a shell *script*, named `foo`

```
#!/bin/zsh -f

source ~/.zshrc   # or just the desired function to save parsing time
# use some functions defined in ~/.zshrc

print "FOO"
```

Comment: "new, non-interactive shell" was the info I was looking for. Thanks!